# Import Thunderbird Lightning Calendar events and tasks into new environment

Tags: thunderbird, lightning

My Ubuntu-installation stopped working correctly, but I managed to make a copy of my personal files. Now I'm trying to setup Thunderbird + Lightning on an another computer (Windows 7). Mail no problem, just copying correct folders of TB profile. But what about my events and tasks? I see a map called 'calendar-data' with file 'local.sqlite', but just copying this to the new environment doesn't give me back my events and tasks. Yes, I did add the Lightning add-on of course.

Answer (score 1):

Mozilla lists tyhe following files at http://kb.mozillazine.org/Files_and_folders_in_the_profile_-_Thunderbird for the Lightning calendatr:

1. cache.sqlite
2. local.sqlite (which you've already brough over)
3. permissions.sqlite
4. storage.sdb

In addition, you can import any .ics files that you might have added.

Let me know if this fixes the issue.

Comment: Nope. Did not work for me. But I did a complete reinstall of the Ubuntu-computer and install of TB + Lightning and copied the complete profile back to this installation. After starting TB, it complained about an outdated version of Lightning, I did an update and everything works fine now, I can see all my events and tasks! Will make a export to be safe now.